# Converting force of interest

Tags: finance, economics

If you have a force of interest (delta) which is expressed biannually and is non-constant, is there a way in which I can express this annually?
E.g first half year, delta = 0.05 and second half year, delta= 0.07 then the annual delta value would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "average" interest rate for the two periods (as long as they are of equal length) is the solution $r$ to the equation
$$
(1.05)(1.07) = (1+r)^2
$$
since these are the factors you  multiply the principal by.

The answer is
$$
r = 0.05995282914
$$
or just a tiny fraction less than the $6\%$ you'd get by just averaging the interest rates.

If $5$ and $7$ percent rates are themselves annual then your equation is
$$
(1.025)(1.035) = (1+r/2)^2
$$
and the solution is
$$
r = 0.05997572801
$$
(not very different).